# Does "request" follow redirects from meta refresh tags?

Tags: node.js, redirect, request

In my nodejs program, I'm using require(request). It doesn't seem to be following redirects even though it should be by default.
I even explicitly set the redirect flag (even though this should be set by default)

```
var options = {
    url:url
  , followRedirect: true
  , headers: { 
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36'
  }
}
request(options, function (err, res, body) {...
```

For example, check out the site http://www.fanniemae.com/
which redirects to http://www.fanniemae.com/portal/index.html

Inside the /index.html, the html contains this

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/portal/index.html">
```

request doesn't seem to be following this meta tag redirect.

Is this normal? And how can I make it follow that redirect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Request** doesn't render pages as browsers do, it's just a way to make simple http calls (redirects would work if there were server-side redirects on external services). So that's why it can't understand this kind of redirect.

As a solution you could try to use something like `PhantomJS` (http://phantomjs.org/) to make it worked with some workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389). 
Or probably scripts written for `Selenium` server might help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post while having the same problem. I extracted the refresh URL and made another request to get the page contnt like this:

```
var regex = /<meta http-equiv="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=([^"]+)[^>]+>/;
var match = regex.exec(response.body);

if (match[1] !== undefined) {
  request.get({
    url: host + match[1],
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(error, response, body);
  });
} else {
  console.log('no meta redirect found :(');
}
```